# How can I update date using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update the `flight_date` field in a table. I want to set the new flight_date which reflects the time after a delay of 4 hours. The date format in MySQL is `YYYY-MM-DD`. Which function has to be used  to implement the change.
Please someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the MySQL function [**`DATE_ADD`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) like the below example:

```
UPDATE your_table_name
   SET flight_date = DATE_ADD(flight_date, INTERVAL 4 HOUR)
 WHERE flight_id = 1
```

**NOTE:** *don't forget to change `your_table_name` and `flight_id` to reflect your table name and field name respectively.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `INTERVAL`, like this:

```
UPDATE your_table_name_goes_here
SET flight_date = flight_date + INTERVAL 4 HOUR
WHERE some_id_field = 123
```

Note that there is no `s` on the end of `HOUR`.

You haven't told us how you named your table or will identify the flight in question, so you will need to edit those portions of the query above (`your_table_name_goes_here` and `some_id_field = 123`).

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use string to date, i.e. 'str_to_date' as described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date and then add an interval.

For example:

```
mysql> SELECT time_format(STR_TO_DATE('2013,01,05,06,00','%Y,%m,%d,%h,%y') + INTERVAL 4 HOUR);
-> '2013-01-05 10:00 '
```